# How to make rel=external open in a new window?

Tags: angularjs

In jQuery, i was able to to something like the following:

```
$('a[rel=external]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

This would make all the [rel=external] urls open in a new window/tab. How can I do the same in Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in vanilla JavaScript, if you don't want to use jQuery

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel=external]')
               , function(elem){
                   elem.setAttribute('target','_blank')
               });
```

Or you can use the angular.element as the jQuery function, more on that in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

`angular.element('a[rel=external]').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: There is no Angular way of doing it? I don't mind doing this but I just want to know.

Comment: angular.element is a jqlite , you con treat it as the jQuery function most of the time: more on that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)
`angular.element('a[rel=external]').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear on what I meant. Is there a way I can do this with angular directives? After googling for a while I found out about creating my own directive (call it like ng-external). If I do this though, will this affect the SEO as I am not explicitly calling "rel=external"?